# pandas add columns with values only

Tags: python, pandas

i have a df with multiple columns and sometimes the column is null. I would like to concat columns that are ONLY populated. Right now I am just adding all columns and have a lot of blank spaces.

```
Num    Country   City
1        USA      
2               Philly
```

So i would like the a 4th column that is

```
Num    Country   City  Total
1        USA             1,USA
2               Philly   2,Philly
```

But this is what i am getting

```
Num    Country   City  Total
1        USA             1,USA, 
2               Philly   2, ,Philly
```

Comment: And what code are you using to achieve it?

Comment: literally just doing df['Country]' + ',' + df['City']+...

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension as well. It should be quick and readable:

```
df['total'] = [', '.join([j for j in i.astype(str) if j != '']) for i in df.values]
```

Here is a full example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = '''\
Num,Country,City
1,USA,
2,,Philly
'''

df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data)).fillna('')

cols = ['Num','Country','City']

df['total'] = [', '.join([j for j in i.astype(str) if j != '']) for i in df[cols].values]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out nulls.

```
df.apply(lambda row: ", ".join(row[i] for i in df.columns if ~pd.isnull(row[i])]),
         axis=1)
```

Comment: what if i wanted to filter out certain columns based on name? could i make a variable with teh column names and swap that for columns?

Comment: Yup! That should work. And actually `columns` is a typo - it should be `df.columns`. Fixing it now.

Comment: or i could modify your if clause? is there a way to add something like if the column name contains the string "hi"

Comment: Yes, but once you get into regex matching you probably want to ask another question :-).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution, similar in methodology to @AntonvBR, but slightly different in the mechanics:

```
df['total'] = [', '.join(list(filter(None, i))) for i in df.values.astype(str)]

   Num Country    City      total
0    1     USA             1, USA
1    2          Philly  2, Philly
```